# Android displayed of a landscape ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have an issue. I develop with Android Studio.
I have a very beautiful landscape imageview like this one <3:
http://www.barrymellorphotography.co.uk/assets/Uploads/landscapes-13.jpg

I want to display it on the phone (landscape or portrait orientation whatever), so that it takes the whole parent layout width, and takes the necessary height size (proportionnally). But I don't reach this goal :(

First the displayed picture quality is very very worse than the picture I want to import: I think it is because Android Studio reduces it to put it in the different folders (hdpi, mdpi...) and after with the quality of the small picture it extends to put in the phone!

Second it doesn't take the whole width... On the left and right stay 2 or 3 dps! And the height is minimal (1dp) and not proportionnally :(

Below I explain how I do to import and display the picture, if someone has an answer to it, thank you!

---

1- I click on new Image Asset!

2- In the asset Studio I choose:

- Asset Type: Launcher Icons
- Foreground: Image
- Foreground scaling: Center
- Shape: None
- Name: banniere

I click OK => The picture is sent to mipmap folders

3- In the activity XML file which displays it I do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bleuclair"
    tools:context=".Aproposde">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aproposdebanniere"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@mipmap/banniere"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the Image Asset tool, that's only for icons.
Just put the jpg to `res/drawable` folder (create the `drawable` folder if not exists) and then change the ImageView like below.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/aproposdebanniere"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/landscape"/>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for :) Very thank you. If i could upvote 100 times your post I would do it! :) I didn't know I could put directly pictures on the drawable folder. But now I have one more little issue which results of this: my picture is in the center of the screen vertically, and it remains like this when i add android:alignParentTop="true" or android:layout_gravity = "top" or android:gravity = "top". Do you know how I can resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: add this attribute `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` inside the ImageView. Cheers :) @dam

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Read the different types of Scale Types that Android uses. `fitCenter` will scale your image. Try `centerInside`. That seems to be more what you are looking for.